# Angular 2 Router gives error when parent of children parameters has a component assigned to it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

The following router configuration gives me an error:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'group/:groupID',
    component: ExampleComponent1,
    children: [
      { path: 'grid/:gridID', component: ExampleComponent2 },
    ]
  }
];
```

Results in:

```
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'ExampleComponent1'
```

But if I comment out the line `component: ExampleComponent1,`, then it works fine.

Shouldn't I be able to specify a component that displays when the grid parameter is omitted? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExampleComponent1 needs to include a Router Outlet.

Somewhere in that component's template, you need to include a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag.  This tag is the marking point for where your ExampleComponent2 will be inserted into ExampleComponent1 when you navigate to that URL.

Comment: Thank you, savior. That absolutely worked, and helps me understand Angular Router. Very interesting.